# Slicing/Splitting certain characters from the csv file name

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, append

I am using pandas library to read 30 csv files in the folder. The following are the name of the files located in the folder "deg_pvsyst_runs" in the path 
**S:/Home/deg_pvsyst_runs/**:

Files are named as:

> ```
>  "Energy_Base_Year00_-0.6%modqual.csv",
>  "Energy_Base_Year01_-0.3%modqual.csv",  ......,  
>  "Energy_Base_Year30_-8.4%modqual.csv
> ```

I want to append list named **"Year"** and **"Degradation"** from the file name above.

"Year" should be single digit **0,1,2,...,30** AND "Degradation" should be  **-0.6, -0.3,0,...,8.1** from the files "Energy_Base_Year00_-0.6%modqual.csv", "Energy_Base_Year01_-0.3%modqual.csv", ..., "Energy_Base_Year30_-8.4%modqual.csv, respectively.

My code below:

```
     import os, csv, re
     import pandas as pd

     Year =[]
     Degradation = []

     cwd = os.getcwd()
     csv_files = [f for f in os.listdir(cwd + '\\' + 'deg_pvsyst_runs') if f.endswith('.csv')]

     for i,j in enumerate(csv_files):
         Year.append(csv_files[i].split("_Year")[1].split("_")[0])
         Degradation.append(csv_files[i].split("_")[1].split("modqual")[0])
```

Eventually, I want to print result in csv named "results.csv" like below (only 2 rows of 30 rows show):

[image]

[EDIT]:

```
    I am getting output 

    Year as ['00','01'...'30'] and Base as ['Base'.'Base'...'Base']

    Whereas I want output as
    Year as ['0','1',...,'30'] and Base as ['-0.6','-0.3','0',...,'8.4']
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Please list error or rephrase your question.

Comment: @Poojan I just added more lines in the end to show my error.

Comment: Is your folder name's format and length consistent ? If so, you can use a simple slice notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Here assuming you need year as `int` and degradation as `float`.
- If you want Degradation as `str` just remove float option.
- The following two line assume consistent input as given in example.

```
Year.append(int(csv_files[i].split("_Year")[1].split("_")[0])) #if you want year as string you can map this to str again to get them as string.
Degradation.append(float(csv_files[i].split("_")[3].split("%modqual")[0]))
```

Comment: This work extremely well. Is this the best way to usually go for slicing/splitting? Thanks for your detailed reply!

Comment: From your input text structure you should come up with best which covers all case. For your case yes you can say its a good solution. Note that this will fail if you have some non numeric character after `_Year` or before `%modqal`. In that case your logic will change.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following approach:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

years, degradations = [], []
cwd = os.getcwd()
csv_files = [f for f in os.listdir(os.path.join(cwd, 'deg_pvsyst_runs')) if f.endswith('.csv')]

for f in csv_files:
    *name_parts, deg = os.path.basename(f).split('_')
    years.append(int(name_parts[-1].replace('Year', '')))
    degradations.append(deg[:deg.index('%')])

pd.DataFrame({'Year': years, 'Degradation': degradations, 'Folder': csv_files})\
    .to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension to achieve this

```
Year = [k.split("_Year")[1].split("_")[0] for k in csv_files]
Year = [y[1] if y.startswith('0') else y for y in Year]
Degradation = [k.split("_")[-1].split(r"%modqual")[0] for k in csv_files]
```

Comment: This approach works well too. Do you prefer this over a single for loop method as I was trying?